# Variations of double slit experiment with their results to look up

Tags: quantum-mechanics, double-slit-experiment

Are there variations of double slit experiment with their results to look up? For example, besides the two parallel slits, having two holes or two slits at 90 degree angles?

Comment: The double slit experiment is a thought experiment, and it is not as important as people make it out to be. It is just a case where diffraction and quantum mechanics coincide, so it is useful for classical thinking people. Dirac uses polarizers, which is clearer because the Hilbert space is finite dimensional.

Answer (score 2):

You might be interested in this paper https://arxiv.org/abs/0811.2068. Here, they perform an experimental test of Born's rule using not two, but three slits.

Comment: Indeed that is type of thing that I am intrested, time to spice up the double slit experiment!

Comment: Although this is strictly speaking a double-slit experiment, it is one of the great achievements of last year, so perhaps it sparks your curiosity as well: http://www.sciencemag.org/content/332/6034/1170.short